# Save the current bash script again

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Is it possible to resave the running bash script?

I am running a loop in the bash file to do certain operations. After the execution of operations are completed, I want to resave the current bash file without adding any extra code. I just want the file last modified date to be changed.

Current code run.sh looks something like

```
#!/bin/bash
FILES=/home/shell/test/*

for f in $FILES
do
if [[ "$f" != *\.* ]]
then
  DO STUFF
fi
done
```

After done, I want run.sh to have current date and possible to do this internally?

Comment: There isn't anything fancy in the code. I'm just testing if I can modify the run.sh file's modifed date internally.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `touch` command in your script:

```
touch "$0"
```

Comment: Just what I want. Thanks!